# How to turn on 'Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors' in Microsoft Visio?

Tags: .net, vsto, ms-office, visio

Microsoft Word has this option to get extra debugging info for Office VSTO solutions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2019

I cannot locate this option in Microsoft Visio in this location or under Add-ins in the Options menu.

Is there any way to turn this on in Visio? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you see a developers tab on the ribbon or on the settings dialog?

Comment: Thank you for following this up Eugene in Visio (2019) I do have the Developer ribbon turned on but in Visio Options there is no Developer section. Can't find this option on the ribbon in Visio, any idea of how to turn it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have just read a related article from David Parker here:

https://bvisual.net/2021/11/05/spotting-custom-ui-errors-in-visio-add-ins

He says **this option is office-wide**, so enabling it in Excel for example should also enable it for Visio.

Comment: Nikolay thank you this is exactly the solution I am looking for!